# pm2 myapp version shown N/A even my package.json have version is there it not showing the version

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, logging, deployment, pm2

below the cmd i used inititally pm2 start npm --name "dev_sandbox-b2b-common-gateway-service" -- start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6g6L.png)

I try to change the verison in my package.json but it showing the pm2 l cmd.
I need show in version pm2 l cmd for respective package.json file.